# Files Deleted from GitHub makes Repo larger

Tags: git, github

Using Mac
BFG is not installed. Wanted to understand Git Filter-Branch first

Problem: I've been able to delete some files from my Git Repos (other files don't seem to want to delete), however, each time I do get a file to delete the repo increases in size. This is NOT what I want to do. I feel like Github is saving something somewhere but I am unsure how to target it.

What I want to do: Delete files and history (to shrink the repo size).

I've followed the procedures here starting with Cleaning the Files and ending with Push the Repository. I'v been targeting random files in attempt to better understand how to delete a file. I've been working in a local repo and then pushing to the remote on GitHub.

1. $ git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch RandomFileName' --prune-empty -f -- --all

I get this which seems to be on the right track

2. rm -rf .git/refs/original/
   This does not seem to do anything
3. git reflog expire --expire=now --all
   This does not seem to do anything
4. git gc --prune=now

5.git gc --aggressive --prune=now

6. git push origin --force --all

7.git push origin --force --tags (not displayed in the code below)

```
Patricks-Air:github-gem PatCosta$ git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch manifest' --prune-empty -f -- --all
Rewrite a34114662b3f3856a9683dc80d0e8f8567ec28c5 (579/579)
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/fallthrough' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/gist' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/keithpitt-ruby-1.9-update' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/organizations' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/upload' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/REL-0.4.2' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/REL-0.4.3' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/REL-0.4.4' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/v0.1.3' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/v0.3.10' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/v0.3.9' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/v0.4.6' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/v0.5.0' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/v0.6.0' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/v0.6.1' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/v0.6.2' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/v0.7.0' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/v0.7.1' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/v0.7.2' is unchanged
REL-0.4.2 -> REL-0.4.2 (135ecb3160aa8d40f20ff5c2ad6da5ffca17048f -> 135ecb3160aa8d40f20ff5c2ad6da5ffca17048f)
REL-0.4.3 -> REL-0.4.3 (abea096a9b376d52d9f39ff0d5623b53f879864d -> abea096a9b376d52d9f39ff0d5623b53f879864d)
REL-0.4.4 -> REL-0.4.4 (0e572e1a5e6daaff68a42500015684b078b50545 -> 0e572e1a5e6daaff68a42500015684b078b50545)
v0.1.3 -> v0.1.3 (bc3b1ecc90460df1656c22db8190ff1e4d2f119b -> bc3b1ecc90460df1656c22db8190ff1e4d2f119b)
v0.3.10 -> v0.3.10 (d372fd6e803d3ba0cdb39f90a6a5a23a721b6673 -> d372fd6e803d3ba0cdb39f90a6a5a23a721b6673)
v0.3.9 -> v0.3.9 (ad3a27c8f693d4126fb689366f5d92d241aa77b6 -> ad3a27c8f693d4126fb689366f5d92d241aa77b6)
v0.4.6 -> v0.4.6 (cff9e1238da21e310f5387117f69e2e6a147183d -> cff9e1238da21e310f5387117f69e2e6a147183d)
v0.5.0 -> v0.5.0 (582a27923455d89e7cfcf1779ff1f371bd585911 -> 582a27923455d89e7cfcf1779ff1f371bd585911)
v0.6.0 -> v0.6.0 (a1eb11c388eb37c4ad5f2b66d3a8a1653409b248 -> a1eb11c388eb37c4ad5f2b66d3a8a1653409b248)
v0.6.1 -> v0.6.1 (7b02b0ea6859da0dbc07e2218ec295b4ef34dff5 -> 7b02b0ea6859da0dbc07e2218ec295b4ef34dff5)
v0.6.2 -> v0.6.2 (9002b9262ea79c50b1421ff805db238471e14a2f -> 9002b9262ea79c50b1421ff805db238471e14a2f)
v0.7.0 -> v0.7.0 (b9ac57b884536a50caa91123756f09df49632545 -> b9ac57b884536a50caa91123756f09df49632545)
v0.7.1 -> v0.7.1 (cf2a1493bd84a8257570e18bea4bc68907083534 -> cf2a1493bd84a8257570e18bea4bc68907083534)
v0.7.2 -> v0.7.2 (6f1a10f16d311b6db8ce4f98f633d276830ce952 -> 6f1a10f16d311b6db8ce4f98f633d276830ce952)
Patricks-Air:github-gem PatCosta$ rm -rf .git/refs/original/
Patricks-Air:github-gem PatCosta$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all
Patricks-Air:github-gem PatCosta$ git gc --prune=now
Counting objects: 2432, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (934/934), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2432/2432), done.
Total 2432 (delta 1474), reused 2432 (delta 1474)
Patricks-Air:github-gem PatCosta$ git gc --aggressive --prune=now
Counting objects: 2432, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2408/2408), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2432/2432), done.
Total 2432 (delta 1474), reused 958 (delta 0)
Patricks-Air:github-gem PatCosta$ git push origin --force --all
Everything up-to-date
Patricks-Air:github-gem PatCosta$ git gc --prune=now --aggressive
Counting objects: 2432, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2408/2408), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2432/2432), done.
Total 2432 (delta 1474), reused 958 (delta 0)
Patricks-Air:github-gem PatCosta$  git push origin master --force
```

Source sites
http://stevelorek.com/how-to-shrink-a-git-repository.html
https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/

Comment: Is it only the GitHub repository that grows, or does your local one grow as well?